# How to configure GraphQL transform in Amplify to include more queries/mutations/subscriptions when creating a GraphQL API

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-amplify, aws-appsync

In the [docs](https://aws-amplify.github.io/docs/cli-toolchain/graphql) we see

```
directive @model(
    queries: ModelQueryMap,
    mutations: ModelMutationMap,
    subscriptions: ModelSubscriptionMap
) on OBJECT
input ModelMutationMap { create: String, update: String, delete: String }
input ModelQueryMap { get: String, list: String }
input ModelSubscriptionMap {
    onCreate: [String]
    onUpdate: [String]
    onDelete: [String]
    level: ModelSubscriptionLevel
}
enum ModelSubscriptionLevel { off public on }
```

> Generates
>
> A single @model directive configures the following AWS
>   resources:
>
> Up to 8 resolvers (create, update, delete, get, list, onCreate,
>   onUpdate, onDelete) but this is configurable via the queries,
>   mutations, and subscriptions arguments on the @model directive.

**My Question**

How is this configuration done? For example I would like to add two **'list'** queries to my API one for the BaseQuery and the second for a DeltaQuery that will be used for DeltaSync?

Thanks in Advance